# error: request for member 'code' in something not a structure or union

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I have a lex and yacc files.

lex - tokens.l
yacc - expression.y

I use flex for lex and bison for yacc

expressions.y:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "../lex/lex.yy.c"
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *s);
int i=0;
%}

%union {
    char *lexeme;
    char *value;
    char *code;
    char *addr;
    struct {
        char *code;
        char *addr;
    } exp;
};

%left '+' '-'
%token <lexeme> id
%token <value> LITERAL
%type <code> S
%type <exp> E

%%

S : id '=' E {
    char *code = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // Adjust size accordingly
    sprintf(code, "%s=%s", $1.lexeme, $3.exp.addr);
    $$.code = code;
}


E : E '+' E {
    char *temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // Adjust size accordingly
    sprintf(temp, "t%d", i++);
    $$.exp.addr = temp;

    char *code = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // Adjust size accordingly
    sprintf(code, "%s=%s+%s", $$.exp.addr, $1.exp.addr, $3.exp.addr);
    $$.exp.code = code;
}
| '-' E {
    char *temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); // Adjust size accordingly
    sprintf(temp, "t%d", i++);
    $$.exp.addr = temp;

    char *code = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // Adjust size accordingly
    sprintf(code, "%s=-%s", $$.exp.addr, $2.exp.addr);
    $$.exp.code = code;
}
| '(' E ')' {
    $$.exp.addr = $2.exp.addr;
    $$.exp.code = $2.exp.code;
}
| id {
    $$.exp.addr = $1.lexeme;
    $$.exp.code = "";
};


%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parser error: %s\n", s);
}

int main() {
    yyparse(); // Start parsing
    return 0;
}
```

tokens.l

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h";

typedef struct SymbolTable{
  char token[10];
  char attr[100];
  char type[10];
} SymbolTable;

SymbolTable ST[1000];
int STn=0;

void printST(){
  int i;
  printf("\nPrinting Symbol Table ");
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    printf("\n%s : %s",ST[i].token, ST[i].attr);
  }
}

int installID(char *a, char *t){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    if((strcmp(ST[i].token, "ID")==0)&&(strcmp(ST[i].attr, a)==0)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  strcpy(ST[STn].token,"ID");
  strcpy(ST[STn].attr,a);
  strcpy(ST[STn].type,t);
  STn++;
  return STn-1;
}

int installLit(char *b, char *t){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<STn;i++){
    if((strcmp(ST[i].token, "NUM")==0)&&(strcmp(ST[i].attr, b)==0)){
      return i;
    }
  }
  strcpy(ST[STn].token,"LITERAL");
  strcpy(ST[STn].attr,b);
  strcpy(ST[STn].type,t);
  STn++;
  return STn-1;
}


%}

id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*

int [-]?[0-9]+
float [-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?
bool "True" | "False"
str (\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|('([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')

%%

%union {
    char *lexeme;
    char *value;
}

%token <lexeme> ID

{id} {
    printf("\nIdentifier : %s ", yytext);
    int a = installID(yytext, NULL);
    yylval.lexeme = strdup(yytext);
    return ID;
}

{int} {printf("\nInteger : %s ",yytext);
      int a = installLit(yytext,"INT");
      yylval.value = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}

{str} {printf("String ");
      int a = installLit(yytext,"STR");
      yylval.value = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}

{float} {printf("Float ");
      int a = installLit(yytext,"FLOAT");
      yylval.value = strdup(yytext);
      return LITERAL;}
%%

int yywrap(){
  return 1;
}
```

when I run

```
flex tokens.l
bison expressions.y
>gcc expressions.tab.c ../lex/lex.yy.c -o myprg && myprg
In file included from expressions.y:5:0:
tokens.l:5:33: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
In file included from expressions.y:5:0:
tokens.l: In function 'yylex':
tokens.l:69:1: error: expected expression before '<' token
In file included from expressions.y:5:0:
tokens.l:74:11: error: request for member 'lexeme' in something not a structure or union
In file included from expressions.y:5:0:
tokens.l:80:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
tokens.l:81:14: error: 'LITERAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
tokens.l:81:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
In file included from expressions.y:5:0:
tokens.l:85:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
In file included from expressions.y:5:0:
tokens.l:90:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
expressions.y: In function 'yyparse':
expressions.y:32:45: error: request for member 'lexeme' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=%s", $1.lexeme, $3.exp.addr);
                                             ^
expressions.y:32:79: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=%s", $1.lexeme, $3.exp.addr);
                                                                               ^
expressions.y:33:11: error: request for member 'code' in something not a structure or union
     $$.code = code;
           ^
expressions.y:40:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.addr = temp;
           ^
expressions.y:43:37: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=%s+%s", $$.exp.addr, $1.exp.addr, $3.exp.addr);
                                     ^
expressions.y:43:70: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=%s+%s", $$.exp.addr, $1.exp.addr, $3.exp.addr);
                                                                      ^
expressions.y:43:103: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=%s+%s", $$.exp.addr, $1.exp.addr, $3.exp.addr);
                                                                                                       ^
expressions.y:44:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.code = code;
           ^
expressions.y:49:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.addr = temp;
           ^
expressions.y:52:35: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=-%s", $$.exp.addr, $2.exp.addr);
                                   ^
expressions.y:52:68: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     sprintf(code, "%s=-%s", $$.exp.addr, $2.exp.addr);
                                                                    ^
expressions.y:53:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.code = code;
           ^
expressions.y:56:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.addr = $2.exp.addr;
           ^
expressions.y:56:45: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.addr = $2.exp.addr;
                                             ^
expressions.y:57:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.code = $2.exp.code;
           ^
expressions.y:57:45: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.code = $2.exp.code;
                                             ^
expressions.y:60:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.addr = $1.lexeme;
           ^
expressions.y:60:45: error: request for member 'lexeme' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.addr = $1.lexeme;
                                             ^
expressions.y:61:11: error: request for member 'exp' in something not a structure or union
     $$.exp.code = "";
           ^
tokens.l:5:33: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive
tokens.l: In function 'yylex':
tokens.l:69:1: error: expected expression before '<' token
tokens.l:74:11: error: request for member 'lexeme' in something not a structure or union
tokens.l:80:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
tokens.l:81:14: error: 'LITERAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
tokens.l:81:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
tokens.l:85:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
tokens.l:90:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
```

All the members that are mentioned in the error message are in the union. But the error persists. I have referred many questions in SO but couldn't find a solution

Kindly Help

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
#include "../yacc/grammer.tab.h";
```

to

```
#include "../yacc/expressions.tab.h";
```

works